# Copy site from one multisite to another

Tags: multisite, migration, export, backup, clone-site

I have a live multisite and a development version of the live multisite.
The top level sites are different, but all the other sites are (or more accurately, will be) the same.

I need to export one of sites from the live multisite and import it into the development multisite, including all content, images, settings menus etc.

I've already created a blank site on the development multisite, so the site id's match.
However, the domains don't quite match.

Live: sitename.websites.domain.com
Development: sitename.www.domain.com

I'm using the domain mapping plugin to achieve: sitename.domain.com for each site.

What is the best approach to copy the site from one multisite to another?

Comment: It's better to use Export and Import from Tools in admin

Comment: Hi @PHPWeblineindia. That was my initial thought. But it doesn't seem to take care of the theme, settings, menus etc.

Comment: @Chris did you find any solutions to this?